# JPA doesn't remove childs while updating parent in web app

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Author entity has collection of Advertisement objects(One-To-Many bidirectional relationship) and collection of Phone(One-To-Many unidirectional relationship).

**Author**

```
public class Author {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String nameOfAuthor; 

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)  
    @JoinTable(name = "author_phone",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "author_fk_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "phone_fk_id"))
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    private List<Phone> phones = new LinkedList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
                orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        private List<Advertisement> advertisements = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

**Phone**

```
public class Phone {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "phone_number")
    private String phoneNumber;
}
```

**Advertisement**

```
public class Advertisement {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "advert_author_id_fk")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private Author author;
}
```

Method for saving Author:

```
public void add(Author author) {             

        em.persist(author);
    }
```

Method for updating Author:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
public void update(Author author) {
    Author merge = em.merge(author);
    em.persist(merge);    
}
```

When I sending json for updatig existing in database Author like this:

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "nameOfAuthor": "Segey",
  "advertisements": [],
    "phones":[]
}
```

Json for saving author:

```
{
  "nameOfAuthor": "Segey",

  "advertisements":[],
  "phones":[
    {
    "phoneNumber": "33333"
    }
    ]
}
```

I don't know why JPA deletes all `phones`, but not `advertisements`.

Comment: @pirho, yes, I use Hibernate, add descriptions  of classes

Comment: Why the join table?

Comment: @pirho becuase I need unidirectional One-To-Many relationship between Author and Phone

Comment: Meaning that you are not willing / it is not possible to add `Author` into the `Phone` for some reason?

Comment: @pirho I no need have field author in Phone class

Comment: @pirho I've added method for saving Author. Agree with your comment about remove call persist method EntityManager.

Comment: I meant that when you pass the param author to method: how do you construct the author before update.

Comment: @pirho Added json in code

Comment: @pirho And after saving Author I saving Advertisiment via JSON

Comment: So it comes from some Spring controller or so? The instance of author?

Comment: @priho yes, it comes from controller, and controller get it via binding from JSON